# Progress Dialog over Content Resolver

Tags: android, cursor, progressdialog

When i am fetching contacts list through following statement, the UI hangs up and shows black screen. How can we place progressDialog during the time this query executes?

```
    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[] { contact_id }, null);
```

Placing dialog.show and dialog.dismiss above and below the statement does not work.

Comment: Did you tried Loaders?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) for such type of requirement. Its the best way to load huge data from the content provider and its asynchronous. You can find more details about it, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).